# How to create n lists in function of x python

Tags: python, list

I have a python code where I want to open N files, and for each file, get 3 separate lists for particulars in X and Y (the last one for weight).

I managed to read a file, and to store it in different lists which are stored in a "main" list which stores lists.

But when my code reads the second file, I did the same as the first with the same name of list. But when I print the main list, it shows me L2 L2 for example, instead of L1 L2

I know this is because I use the same list, x1 for the 2 files and so the variable just change in final list, but as of right now, I have no clue on how to get something working right.

Here's the code

```
import os
x1 = []
y1 = []
p1 = []
Xtotal = []
Ytotal = []
listcount = 0
def stockage(z):
    compteur = 0
    del x1[:]
    del y1[:]
    del p1[:]
    for ligne in z :
        if ligne[0:1]=='#':
            pass
        else:
            if ligne[0:1]=='p':
                p1.append(float(ligne[2:]))
            else:
                compteur = compteur + 1
                if compteur%2 == 0 :    
                    y1.append(float(ligne.rstrip()))
                else:
                    x1.append(float(ligne.rstrip()))
    Xtotal.append(x1)
    Ytotal.append(y1)
    print(Xtotal)
for fichier in os.listdir('data/'):
    fichierOuvert = open("data/"+fichier, "r")
    listetotale=stockage(fichierOuvert)
    fichierOuvert.close()
print(Xtotal)
print(x1)
print(y1)
print(p1)
```

And here's a sample file which is used as an imput :

'#'This file contains points particulars and the line with p= its weight

'#'PointA :
p=20

12

22

'#PointB :'

34

26

'#PointC :'

28

98

'#PointD :'

97

54

Comment: What do you mean it's python(ish)?  Why ish?

Comment: Also, if you could edit the question to include the code you have so far that is relevant to your problem (a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), we will be better able to help you

Comment: Ish, because i'm a beginer and i'm not sure if i'm doing things the proper way

Comment: Your example still isn't complete or verifiable (See the page linked to by my previous comment).  We need to know what the argument to your function is, how the file you're reading is structured, and the definitions of all of your variables (what are x1, y1, p1, etc.).

Comment: Alright, added whole thing
Didn't did it at first because i thought it would be useless but here we are, thnak you btw

Comment: so you get the contents of the first file, add references to `x1` which contains that data, then `del x1[:]` so you erase the contents you got, fill it back up with stuff from the second file (so the `x1` you appended at first now holds the second file contents) and then add a second reference to `x1` to your master list... find a way to do it without `del x1[:]` and it will almost certainly work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you're getting for Xtotal currently looks something like this:

```
[x1, x1]
```

because you're adding the same list twice.  So, when you make changes to x1, you make changes to every list in Xtotal.  Using `del` doesn't change that.  Instead, you want to create entirely new lists each time your function is called.

What you need to do is move the definitions of your lists (`x1 = []`, etc.) into your function (where you currently have `del x1[:]`), and get rid of the lines where you clear out those lists (remove `del x1[:]`, `del y1[:]`, etc.).  You will then have to remove the lines printing `x1`, `y1`, and `p1` from the end of your script, but you can accomplish the same thing by doing

```
print(Xtotal[-1])
print(Ytotal[-1])
```

instead.

If you also add a variable `Ptotal` in the same way you have `Xtotal` and `Ytotal`, then you will have access to `p1` as well, in the same way.

Comment: Holy sh** this does actually work.
Thanks dude, you are the real MVP

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example will demonstrate what is going on:

```
x1 = []
Xtotal = []

def make_some_data(length):
    del x1[:]
    x1.extend(range(length))
    Xtotal.append(x1)

print(Xtotal)
for i in range(1,5):
    make_some_data(i)
    print(Xtotal)

#output
[]
[[0]]
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>> [id(item) for item in Xtotal]
[4386547144, 4386547144, 4386547144, 4386547144]
>>> [id(item)==id(x1) for item in Xtotal]
[True, True, True, True]
```

When you erase the content of the list `x1` you also get rid of the data you previously generated, rendering any reference to it instead point to the new data you fill it up with, instead you need to use local variables to make new lists as you need them:

```
Xtotal = []

def make_some_data(length):
    x1 = []
    x1.extend(range(length))
    Xtotal.append(x1)

print(Xtotal)
for i in range(1,5):
    make_some_data(i)
    print(Xtotal)

#output:
[]
[[0]]
[[0], [0, 1]]
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```